# Copy Columns from a sheet to add at lastcolumn in "archive" sheet with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry for my english. ^^

Erm, i´ve found a script to copy from a sheet to an other Sheet.
My problem is: its copy with rows.
I want to copy columns and add 2 columns to lastcolumn on script running.

It becames a problem, because columns has no a1notification. A=1, B=2, etc.
copyTo wants A1notification.

Heres my script:

```
function Archiv() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetid");
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("sheetnametarget");
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("D4:E89");
var last_col = target_sheet.getLastColumn();
target_sheet.insertColumnAfter(last_col);
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(">>>>(lastcol+1)<<<<4:>>>>>(lastcol+2)<<<<89");
source_range.copyTo(target_range, {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

The script have to run every Monday to archive the content of 2 Columns.
I hope you can understand my wish.
I have tested many things, but nothing helps. :(

Many thanks in advance.

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You can use another range selection mode that will makes things very simple, see [this doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet?hl=fr-FR#getRange), using integers for row and column numbers.

Your code could become like this :

```
function Archiv() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetid");
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("sheetnametarget");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("D4:E89");
  var last_col = target_sheet.getLastColumn();
  while(target_sheet.getMaxColumns()<=last_col+2){// add columns only if necessary
  target_sheet.insertColumnAfter(last_col)}
  var source_values = source_range.getValues();
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(4,last_col+1,source_values.length,2);// row Nr4, starting on last column+1, 2 columns width and 89-4 rows heigth
  target_range.setValues(source_values);
}
```

I used `getValues()` and `setValues()` instead of `copyTo()` that returned an error : *target and source must be in the same spreadsheet*